# How do you update a record on Heroku using the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to update a record on my app hosted by Heroku, but the change keeps reverting. The process works on my local version, so I don't know what's happening.

Rails 5 with Postgres

```
heroku run rails c
new_value = "Some valid value"
post = Post.find(123)
post.update_attribute(:name, new_value)
D, [2017-03-22T17:01:30.955525 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-03-22T17:01:30.961653 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
post.name
=> nil

#Try another way
post.name = new_value
post.valid?
=> true
post.save
D, [2017-03-22T16:53:28.405310 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-03-22T16:53:28.427131 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.5ms)  COMMIT
=> true
p.reload
p.name
=> nil
p.errors.full_messages
=> []
```

Comment: What happens when you try `post.save!(name: new_value)`?

Comment: Hm, I doubt that this issue is related to heroku. I can't tell from here whats going on, but I suspect some hidden issue in your code. Does ist work locally with exactly the some dataset (=> a local clone of the database)? Can you show the code of your Post model? (or if its a lot any code related to name)

Comment: @mmichael no luck 

Comment: @trueunlessfalse There are validations that the value would fail. So I would expect the `.save` method to return false with errors, and the `update_attribute` method to work as it bypasses validations. The `DEBUG` and `D` makes me think the app is in debug mode or something, but I can't find any settings on Heroku for it

Comment: @trueunlessfalse turns out it was the validations stopping it. How strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, a validation in the model was stopping the database from being updated. Which is particularly strange considering `update_attribute` is supposed to bypass validation.

Anyway here was the culprit...

```
format: { with: URI::regexp(["http", "https"]) }
```

...removed this and it worked. Not a great work around though.